# ggplot2 How to align graphs with equal y scale as percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I'm trying to obtain 2 aligned bar plots with percentage scales of 2 different factors. The y scales calculated as percent are different. I would like to have the same y scales for both plots, for example from 0 to 40% in both. I've tried ylim() which doesn't work on the percentage scale. Example below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
data("diamonds")
```

First bar-plot for cut

```
  p<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +  
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=cut)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
    geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = 
    scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
    ggtitle("Cut") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14, 
    face="bold")) + 
    xlab("Cut") +
    ylab("Percent") +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Second bar-plot for clarity

```
p1<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity)) +  
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=clarity)) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = 
scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
        stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
ggtitle("Clarity") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14, 
face="bold")) + 
xlab("Clarity") +
ylab("Percent") +
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Arranging bar-plot with different scales

```
  grid.arrange(p,p1, ncol = 2)
```

different scales but I would like for example both at 40% top

[image]

If scales weren't percentages I would do this:

```
p<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=cut)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  ggtitle("Cut") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14, face="bold")) + 
  xlab("Cut") +
  ylab("Percent") +
  ylim(0, 40)
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

But here, of course, it doesn't work and returns this:

[image]

Comment: use `ylim(0, 0.4)`

Comment: Thanks! definitely better but I lose the scale as integer and % which I kind of liked. Any idea how to preserve that?

Comment: The ylim replaced the existing scale - your solution fixed that

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a way, here the code for Cut for a % scale limited to 60%

```
p<- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=cut)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  ggtitle("Diamonds Cut") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14, face="bold")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(0,0.6)) + labs(y="Percent")
xlab("Cut") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
p
```

[image]